TypeError: functions.database.ref is not a function at Object
I'm trying to deploy my project using Firebase Functions, and encountered this error:
TypeError: functions.database.ref is not a function at Object.

(C:\\Users\\minse\\Downloads\\spj\\spj14 - 복사본 - 복사본 (2)\\functions\\index.js:132:51)

I saw this error and tried to change that line:
exports.onReportStatusChange = functions.database.ref('/reports/{reportId}')

to:
export.onReportStatusChange = functions.database().ref('/reports/{reportId}')

but it still fails.
I'm not sure what the problem is.

Provide [mcve].

In your question, you have forgotten to include the import/require line for the functions object. In your code, this is likely to be:
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

While this used to be correct, the Cloud Functions SDK now imports the V2 APIs by default as of V6.0 of the SDK. This means that the older V1 functions were moved and now need to be imported using:
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");

This means the lines you need to use are:
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");

// ...

exports.onReportStatusChange = functions.database.ref('/reports/{reportId}')

